# How to search for clicked element src attribute and add it to another jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with TB and trying to find solution to combine carousel and modal feature. I know that carousel gallery already exists in ver.3 but I am still working in 2.3 for some reason.

The problem is when user clicks on the carousel on the page it appears modal window and starts to slide images from the begining and not from the current (clicked) image.

Idea is to find that src attribute of clicked element and pass it over to  element within modal window. Any ideas how to do that? Thanks! Here is html structure.

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="modal-trigger" class="modal hide fade modal-trigger slide" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="num"></div>

        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">Schließen</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="myCarousel2" class="carousel slide">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="0" class=" active">&nbsp;</li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="1" class="">&nbsp;</li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="2" class="">&nbsp;</li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="3" class="">&nbsp;</li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="4" class="">&nbsp;</li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="5" class="">&nbsp;</li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="6" class="">&nbsp;</li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="7" class="">&nbsp;</li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="8" class="">&nbsp;</li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="img/1_big.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/4.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/5.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/6.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/7.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/8.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/9.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel2" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel2" data-slide="next">›</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my test js code made for that:

```
$('.carousel').on('slide', function(e) {
                    // var slideFrom = $(this).find('.active').index();
                    // var slideTo = $(e.relatedTarget).index();

                    var clickedItem = $(this);
                    var replacedItem = $('#myCarousel2 .carousel-inner .item.active');

                    $(clickedItem).click(function() {
                        $(this).attr({
                            src: $(this).attr('src'),
                            'src': $(this).attr('src')
                        })
                        console.log("it should replace element src value");
                    });
                    // console.log(slideFrom+' => '+slideTo);
                });
```

Something similar I am trying to achive but only with Twitter Bootstrap 2.3
http://bootdey.com/snippets/view/Bootstrap-Gallery-with-Modal-Lightbox-and-Carousel-114

**This code helped me to open almost the right image in modal window, but unfortunately it picks up allways the image with +1 number of img-data. Does anyone has solution to pick just the right image which in this case is one number lower? **

```
$('#myCarousel .item a').on('click', function() {
                    $('#modal-trigger').carousel(parseInt($(this).children().attr("data-id")));
                    console.log("Code works");
                });
```

Comment: Could you add link to js fiddle, it could be better for your help

Answer (score 0):

try to use trigger `click` on indicator corresponding to the clicked element (using index or id)

```
$('.carousel .someitem').on('click', function() {
  var index = $(this).attr('index'); // or other (what you want)
  $('#modal-trigger .carousel-indicators:eq('+index+')').trigger('click');
});
```

Something like this.
It's not tested.

Comment: Can you please write js for that?

Comment: Don't forget to add index attribute to indicators and slides on page.

Comment: If you add link to fiddle, I could help better :)

Comment: Something similar I am trying to do but only with twitter bootstrap 2.3: http://bootdey.com/snippets/view/Bootstrap-Gallery-with-Modal-Lightbox-and-Carousel-114

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is:

```
                    $('#myCarousel .item a').on('click', function() {

                    var goTo = parseInt($(this).children().attr("data-id"), 10) - 1;
                    if(goTo < 0)
                        goTo = 0;

                    $('#modal-trigger').carousel(goTo);
                    console.log("Code works");
                });
```